# Server error for Intranet zone

Tags: 2007, alternate-access-mapping

There is a web application with one single Site Collection. Alternate access mapping for this web application has been configured to use `http:\\servername:port` for default zone and `http:\\someDomainName.com`for intranet zone. When you browse to `http:\\someDomainName.com`, it generates server error. however when you browse to the default zone `http:\\serverName:Port` it works and shows the site collection. appreciate all kind of advice.

Comment: What are the ULS log showing? Sounds like it can be a problem with a custom component not handling AAM

Comment: Thanks, It was a bit strange, I solved the problem by touching the web.config file.

Comment: Can you explain what you had done in web.config file ? It will be useful for others.

Comment: I opened the web.config file and close it without saving